# How to generate a new value for one column depending on whether it is already available in another column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with an `ID` column (NUMBER) and `PARENT_ID` column (number). When inserting new data, the new ID must be generated using `MAX(ID) + 1` IF the result [MAX(ID) + 1] does not exist in the other column (`PARENT_ID`).

So the data to be inserted into the `ID` column must be the first biggest number from the MAX(ID) that is not available in the `PARENT_ID` column.

I'm trying to achieve this without making a stored procedure out of it (if possible).

The select query I have so far checks whether the next biggest number of the ID column is present in the `PARENT_ID` column and returns it if it's not.

However, I'm not sure how to augment the query to include the scenario where `MAX(ID) + 1` is present in `PARENT_ID`. How do I check the next biggest value?

This is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN MAX(ID) + 1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTCINT PARENT_ID FROM CarteTable) 
          THEN MAX(ID) + 1
    END
FROM CarteTable;
```

This is my table:

```
ID         PARENT_ID
--------------------
1              2
2              3
4              5
```

My query returns nothing in this case.

When I run the query, I need it to return 6 as MAX(ID) + 1 i.e. 5 is present in PARENT_ID. How can I augment my query to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN MAX(ID)+1 <= MAX(PARENT_ID) THEN MAX(PARENT_ID)+1
    ELSE MAX(ID)+1
END New_id
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a case expression like this

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN MAX(ID)  > MAX(PARENT_ID) THEN MAX(ID) + 1
  ELSE MAX(PARENT_ID) + 1 
END as next_id
FROM CarteTable;
```